# Is there an a website to calculate the Gauss-Jordan Elimination in Finite fields GF(p)?

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, gaussian-elimination

Is there  an a website   to  calculate the   Gauss-Jordan Elimination  in Finite fields GF(p) ?

Comment: The user @AviTal wrote the following answer: "Yes, here is a good one: https://matrixer.davidaugustat.com/". Bizarrely, the answer was deleted because "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes." In this case, the link was the essential part of the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Wolfram Alpha will do it: [an example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rowreduce(%5B%5B1,2,3%5D,%5B4,5,6%5D,%5B7,8,9%5D%5D)%20in%20gf(11)).

Comment: I have not enough reputations yet to downvote your answer, but the reason that I want to do that is because that when I tried to calculate the Gauss-Jordan Elimination of some binary matrix over the finite field GF(2) by using the calculator that your "an example" link refers to then the only answer it gave me was "Try the following:" and then an imperative list of tips of what to do and "Other tips for using Wolfram|Alpha:" and then a prohibitive list of tips of what not to do instead of just printing the answer and that's it and the input string was okay and not wrong.

Comment: @ErezZrihen What was your input? When I input "rowreduce([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) in gf(2)" it gives an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [online Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) will do it (and much else besides).  Copying and pasting the following script:

```
A:=Matrix(GF(13),3,5, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,0,1,2]);
print A, EchelonForm(A);
```

into the calculator, for example, produces the following output:
$$
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
[&1&2&3&4&5&]\\
[&6&7&8&9&10&]\\
[&11&12&0&1&2&]
\end{array}\\
\ \\
\ \\
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
[&1&0&12&11&10&]\\
[&0&1&2&3&4&]\\
[&0&0&0&0&0&]
\end{array}
$$